# Адаптивность сортировок

Tags: алгоритм, сортировка

Какие сортировки из списка являются адаптивными, т.е. эффективны при обработке уже отсортированных или частично отсортированных данных:

Быстрая сортировка

Поразрядная сортировка

Сортировка выбором

Сортировка слиянием

Сортировка вставками

Сортировка пузырьком

Сортировка подсчётом

P.S. Это не задание из вуза и т.д. я просто хочу до конца разобраться в этой теме
На мой взгляд пузырьком - адаптивна точно, слиянием - нет, подсчетом - адаптивна, как и поразрядная, выбором - нет, быстрая -нет

Comment: Эх... минус рейтинг

Comment: Пара итераций пузырька, если на третьей встретился неотсортированный item, пропускаем сколько-то итераций, меняющих входные данные.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov а можно подробнее? не очень понял